# Changes made to deployment via k8 dashboard disappear

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to get https://github.com/ansible/awx-operator to import inventories from my git repo and my inventory contains vault secrets so when I attempt to "sync" my AWX ansible inventory with my git repo the job fails with:

```
ERROR! Attempting to decrypt but no vault secrets found
```

There is a workaround for this I am trying to implement.
The workaround is to execute these commands on the "AWX" nodes:

```
echo "XXXXXXXXX" > /tmp/vault_password
chmod 777 /tmp/vault_password
```

and then set extra vars to:

```
---
ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE: /tmp/vault_password
```

awx-operator is an kubernetes deployment so I figured I could edit the pod definitions in the deployment to implement the above workaround, with `kubectl edit deployment -n awx awx-demo`.

I change this ...

```
262       initContainers:
263       - command:
264         - /bin/sh
265         - -c
266         - |
267           hostname=$MY_POD_NAME
268           receptor --cert-makereq bits=2048 commonname=$hostname dnsname=$hostname nodeid=$hostname outreq=/etc/receptor/tls/receptor.req outkey=/etc/receptor/tls/receptor.key
269           receptor --cert-signreq req=/etc/receptor/tls/receptor.req cacert=/etc/receptor/tls/ca/receptor-ca.crt cakey=/etc/receptor/tls/ca/receptor-ca.key outcert=/etc/receptor/tls/receptor.crt verify=yes
```

... to this ...

```
262       initContainers:
263       - command:
264         - /bin/sh
265         - -c
266         - |
267           echo "XXXXXXXXX" > /tmp/vault_password
268           chmod 777 /tmp/vault_password
269           hostname=$MY_POD_NAME
270           receptor --cert-makereq bits=2048 commonname=$hostname dnsname=$hostname nodeid=$hostname outreq=/etc/receptor/tls/receptor.req outkey=/etc/receptor/tls/receptor.key
271           receptor --cert-signreq req=/etc/receptor/tls/receptor.req cacert=/etc/receptor/tls/ca/receptor-ca.crt cakey=/etc/receptor/tls/ca/receptor-ca.key outcert=/etc/receptor/tls
```

But a pod is dying and the deployment reverts back to what I had before I edited it.
I cannot figure out how to see what is the cause of the CrashLoop.

Update:

I managed to grab the error by running `kubectl describe awx-demo` at just the right moment.  And I see:

```
Init Containers:
  init:
    Container ID:  containerd://075110d13705a335850818ca49ba33eec94f4a1db06dfd9ff5b224ee8fd15480
    Image:         quay.io/ansible/awx-ee:latest
    Image ID:      quay.io/ansible/awx-ee@sha256:546c728608e57cb0903e10f4a530e6ff1cd8d94ee9e9bcb7db64f96ede6d0180
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /bin/echo "XXXXXXX" > /tmp/vault_password
      /bin/chmod 777 /tmp/vault_password
      /bin/sh
      -c
      hostname=$MY_POD_NAME
      receptor --cert-makereq bits=2048 commonname=$hostname dnsname=$hostname nodeid=$hostname outreq=/etc/receptor/tls/receptor.req outkey=/etc/receptor/tls/receptor.key
      receptor --cert-signreq req=/etc/receptor/tls/receptor.req cacert=/etc/receptor/tls/ca/receptor-ca.crt cakey=/etc/receptor/tls/ca/receptor-ca.key outcert=/etc/receptor/tls/receptor.crt verify=yes

    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       StartError
      Message:      failed to create containerd task: failed to 
create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: 
unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/echo \"XXXXXXXX\" > 
/tmp/vault_password": stat /bin/echo "XXXXXXXX" > 
/tmp/vault_password: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Comment: Hmmm... how would I handle the '>'?

Comment: Did the below answer resolve the issue?

Comment: Sorry, no it didn't.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? If yes, consider writing as it would help everyone. If not, consider elaborating the issue when the proposed solution is attempted so answer could be improved. Just dont want to leave this hanging open.

Answer (score 1):

As there could be only one process as an entry point, you can have only one command(Eg: `bash`). Try breaking your command with command and args and pass all the commands as commands as args to bash.

```
- command: ["/bin/bash","-c"] 
  args: ["/bin/echo 'XXXXXXX' > /tmp/vault_password && /bin/chmod 777 /tmp/vault_password"]
```

Comment: I wasn't sure where to put the `- command` line so I went with this: `[dumb-init] /usr/bin/echo 'xxxxxxxx' > /vault_password && /usr/bin/chmod 777 /vault_password && /usr/bin/launch_awx.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: Line `263` in your snippet in the question !?